# Какими способами можно реализовать редактирование аудиофайла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

Имеется приложение(на python), которое может открывать аудиофайлы и проигрывать их, с помощью чего можно реализовать редактирование аудиофайлов в данной программе (например обрезать, ускорить, замедлить)

Comment: выбирайте: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic ))